# How can I send email to customer when recurring payment fails on Stripe?

Tags: php, cakephp, stripe-payments

I want my customers to get notified if the recurring payments fail on Stripe.   They should be notified via email that Stripe has declined their Credit Card.  I have read about webhooks but not quite sure how to use them.  And also how can I know every time any card has been declined on Stripe.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with webhooks is that you register a url with the remote party and once they have something to tell you they "call" that url passing it parameters.

With stripe you do that on their dashboard under [webhook settings](https://manage.stripe.com/account/webhooks).

Then all you have to do is apply your logic in the url you supplied. If it is www.example.com/webhooks/stripe then you need a `webhook` controller with a `stripe()` method that will parse the data.

So in your `stripe()` method you wait for the `charge.fail` event (read Stripe's API) and once you get that you send the email and perhaps update your database as well.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I was just so much confused because I was not able to see the Webhooks tab into the Account Settings of Account I was provided with.

Thanks again.